# Dual of the space of all convergent sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I need to find what it wrong with my logic and Ii will be glad if someone can told me what I do wrong.

**Define  $C$ be the subspace of $ l^{\infty} $ that consists of convergent sequences** and let $C_0$ be the subspace of $C$ that consists of sequences that converge to 0.

I need to show that $C_0^*$ is isometric to $l^1$ .

I already show that $C_0$ is isometric to $l^1$ and I want to use the fact that if $Z = X \oplus  Y $ then  $Z^* = X^* \oplus  Y^* $.

So I claim that $ C \cong C_0 \oplus \mathbb C$  because every converge sequence I can write like this:

let $\{x_n\}_{n=1} ^ \infty$  that converge to $d$ then we can look at the following sequence  $y_n =(x_n- d) + d $
by this observation  I conclude that $C \cong C_0 \oplus \mathbb C$
because every constant sequence we can id by  it first element.

Then by what I write above I get  $C^* \cong C_0^* \oplus \mathbb C ^* $.

So I get $C^* \cong l^1 \oplus \mathbb C ^*$
and to get that is isometric to $l^1$ i think that it wrong because I think that there not such a function that will be 1-1 in this case.

So my questions are

1) what I doing wrong, because I need to prove this and not to say that its wrong?

2) If all that I write is correct can I conclude from this that $C_0$ not isometric to $C$ (because $C \cong C_0 \oplus \mathbb C$)?

thank

Comment: I think you meant "I need to show that $C^*$ is isometric to $\ell^1$" and "I have already shown that $C_0^*$ is isometric to $\ell^1$". Otherwise I can't make sense of your question.

Comment: yes i make a mistake you right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use sums of Banach spaces it is better emphasize the type of norm you are using on this sum. With slight modifications your proof reads as follows
$$
c^*\cong(c_0\oplus_\infty\mathbb{C})^*\cong_1 c_0^*\oplus_1\mathbb{C}^*\cong_1 \ell_1\oplus_1\mathbb{C}
$$
It is remains to show that $\ell_1\oplus_1\mathbb{C}\cong_1 \ell_1$, but it is really easy - just consider isometric bijective linear operator
$$
I:\ell_1\oplus_1\mathbb{C}\to\ell_1:(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\oplus_1 z \mapsto(z,x_1,x_2,\ldots)
$$

Comment: thanks :)
second you say that "it is better emphasize the type of norm you are using on this sum" you said that because it make this to be more correct right?

Comment: It makes my proof more clear. In fact $\ell_1\oplus \mathbb{C}\cong \ell_1$ for all standard norms imposed on the sum, BUT if you put $1$-norm on the sum of $\ell_1$ and $\mathbb{C}$, then you get that $\ell_1\oplus_1\mathbb{C}$ is *isometrically* isomorphic to $\ell_1$.

Comment: @Norbert: Where do you get $c^*\cong_1(c_0\oplus_\infty\mathbb{C})^*$ from? Note that $c\cong_1(c_0\oplus_\infty\mathbb{C})$ does not hold.

Comment: @grew, ok now fixed

Comment: @Norbert To show this isomorphism explicitly, could we define $$\rho : \ell^1 \to C*$$ by $$\rho: x \mapsto T_x$$ where $$T_x(a) = \sum \frac{x_na_n}{M}$$ where $M$ is the bound for the sequence $a$? This seems to be an isometric isomorphism

Comment: The map $\rho$ is not even linear because M depends non linearly on a. So your suggestion is wrong

Comment: @Norbert, then how can this proof yield $c^\ast\cong_1 l^1$? Since you only obtain $c\cong l^1\oplus_1\mathbb{C}\cong_1 l^1$.